# How to enable javascript in XWalkView?

Tags: crosswalk-runtime

this URL shows how is *used* to be done:
http://zhangwenli.com/blog/2014/08/25/crosswalk-calling-java-methods-with-javascript/

However, the getSettings() function is now removed.

How does one now enable Javascript ?

Answer (score 11):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private XWalkView xWalkWebView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity_xml);
        xWalkWebView = (XWalkView)findViewById(R.id.xwalkView);
        xWalkWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "Android");
        xWalkWebView.load(url_your_want_to_load,null); 
    }

    public class WebAppInterface {
        @org.xwalk.core.JavascriptInterface
        public void callFunction(){
           // Do your Android Stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Now Call function in your page as:

```
Android.callFunction();
```

Comment: The answer was correct and XWalkView WebView of CrossWalk Project is by default has JavaScript enabled

Comment: I agree, Javascript is on by default.

Comment: Why downvote? 
I +1ed.
@AshutoshSrivastava answered how to solve OP's problem. Not necessarily what the downvoter was looking for.

Comment: `@org.xwalk.core.JavascriptInterface` just saved me from putting a web server in my app.  I had a reference webkit, so `@JavascriptInterface` was pulling in `android.webkit.JavascriptInterface` and leaving my injected objects empty.  You saved me, +1